# Java - String detected as an object

Tags: java, string, actionlistener

I'm trying to make a units converter in java to train myself, but i have a problem here.

I have a button to convert the specified number in the specified unit, so I've made an action listener to my button who call my function `convert()` with three arguments. Theses arguments are a double, and two Strings. But, my string are the units from two `JComboBox`, so i use the method `.getSelectedItem` to get the unit. But, this method apparently return an Object (???) and not a string.

How can i get sure my units are conserved with this method ? Is it possible that my units are not well selected ? How can i get a String to call my `convert()` method ?

Thanks guys !
[Here is an image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuEAu.png)

Comment: Next time, please include a code sample instead of a screenshot. However unlikely, links break sometimes and future visitors will not be able to view what you linked. It also lets editors clean up code samples to make your question more concise.

Comment: `double value = Double.parseDouble("" + val1.getItemAt(val1.getSelectedIndex()));` Does this solve your problem?

Comment: You can always try casting an `Object` to a `String` with `(String) arg`. Assuming the `JComboBox` only has `String`s, a simple cast should fix your issue.

Comment: @Locke Ok sorry for this, its my first post on stackOverflow ;)

Comment: @XO56, no i dont have any problem with the double value only the strings

Comment: @Locke Your solution worked. I casted my arguments in the convert(...) method. Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Always try to use Generics instead of using without type safety like `JComboBox`, the better way is to write like `JComboBox<String>` to avoid any explicit typecasting. For your scenario you could use explicit typecasting also along with the code defined below, both ways should work fine considering the item is selected in the combo box or else the code will land up in some exception.

```
JComboBox<String> units1 = new JComboBox<>(); //use typesafety 
JComboBox<String> units2 = new JComboBox<>(); //use typesafety

String string1 = units1.getModel().getElementAt(units1.getSelectedIndex());
String string2 = units2.getModel().getElementAt(units2.getSelectedIndex());
```

Comment: I tried this but my units are still objects in the convert() function

Comment: it might be because you wouldn't have used the generics while declaring the ```JComboBox``` it's better if you start using the generics wherever it's possible.

```JComboBox<String> unit1 = new JComboBox<>();```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to cast the arguments in the call of the method. As shown in the code

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw36z.png)